# 3D point rotation algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, 3d, rotation

I'm currently working on a JavaScript project which involves 3D point rotation. Using simple trigonometry, I have sketched my own 3D point rotation algorithm, but I have to deal with a huge amount of data (+300 000 points) and my function slows down the runtime substantially (the FPS rate drops from 60 to 12).

> I'm looking for another 3D point rotation **ALGORITHM** which...
>
> 1. rotates points around origin by X, Y and Z axes' angles (PITCH, YAW and ROLL)
> 2. has a quite good efficiency (don't worry about this too much, it will always be faster than mine)
> 3. is written in JavaScript, C-like code or pseudo-code

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

**Context: 3D point cloud renderer (I want every point to be rotated)**

Comment: If you're starting with Euler angles (pitch, yaw, roll) and need to rotate a bunch of points, you might consider first converting the Euler angles to quaternions, then using the quaternions to efficiently implement your rotations.  It's possibly even more efficient than matrices (which you should definitely get comfortable with, if you're going to be doing 3D graphics programming).  At least that should give you a few search terms to work with....

Comment: Point rotation is just a multiplication of a vector with a matrix. That matrix is the same for all points, so it should be determined only once, especially since it requires trig functions. Reducing the number of objects to rotate (becausesome of them are not visible, for example) may yield a better performance, too, if you can determine which objects you want to rotate efficiently.

Comment: Your question doesn't give a lot of context, but another thing is how you represent the objects. You don't represent them in terms of object-fixed coordinates attached to your spaceship (or whatever you have), do you? Instead of rotating the world around you, you can just rotate the ship and just rotate a subset of your many objects for visualisation. (Pluis, repeated rotations about small angles will introduce rounding errors pretty quickly.)

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: I'm working on something like a pointcloud renderer. @M Oehm, yes I know that, but I want every point to be rotated. I know I can reduce the amount of points to be rendered as they're further but for now I have disabled that feature.

Comment: I won't lie you guys. I have no idea what a quaternion or a matrix is, so maybe I'll try to learn that (Khan Academy maybe?) and then answer my own question xD. Meanwhile, every valid answer will be rewarded with an upvote!

Comment: I can do a simple rotation (without translation) for 1,000,000 points in Javascript in 15ms. That's just the transformation, without rendering. For 300,000 points it's 7ms, which gives you nearly 10ms for rendering if you want to keep the 60 fps.

Comment: @MOehm don't worry too much about the timing. I just want another algorithm. I don't really care if it runs at 30FPS or 15. I'm sure that any other algorithm, although it may not be the fastest one, will considerably improve the current FPS rate-

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A rotated vector can be described as a product of a rotation matrix with that vector. The [German Wikipedia page on pitch, roll and yaw](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-Nick-Gier-Winkel) describes the rotation matrix for given Euler rotation angles.

With that information, the rotation of all points with the same angles can be written as JavaScript function, where the points array is global:

```
function rotate(pitch, roll, yaw) {
    var cosa = Math.cos(yaw);
    var sina = Math.sin(yaw);

    var cosb = Math.cos(pitch);
    var sinb = Math.sin(pitch);

    var cosc = Math.cos(roll);
    var sinc = Math.sin(roll);

    var Axx = cosa*cosb;
    var Axy = cosa*sinb*sinc - sina*cosc;
    var Axz = cosa*sinb*cosc + sina*sinc;

    var Ayx = sina*cosb;
    var Ayy = sina*sinb*sinc + cosa*cosc;
    var Ayz = sina*sinb*cosc - cosa*sinc;

    var Azx = -sinb;
    var Azy = cosb*sinc;
    var Azz = cosb*cosc;

    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var px = points[i].x;
        var py = points[i].y;
        var pz = points[i].z;

        points[i].x = Axx*px + Axy*py + Axz*pz;
        points[i].y = Ayx*px + Ayy*py + Ayz*pz;
        points[i].z = Azx*px + Azy*py + Azz*pz;
    }
}
```

Most of that is setting up the rotation matrix as described in the article. The last three lines inside the loop are the matrix multiplication. You have made a point of not wanting to get into matrices, but that's hardly intimidating, is it? Sooner or later you will encounter more matrices and you should be prepared to deal with them. The stuff you need – multiplication, mainly – is simple. The more complicated stuff like inverting matrices is not needed for your requirements.

Anyway, that performs reasonably fast for 300,000 points. I was able to rotate a point cloud of that size and render it on a 1000px &times 1000px canvas in about 10ms.

Comment: Sorry for gravedigging.. But what am I doing wrong if a rotation with roll/yaw and pitch/yaw work good, but roll/pitch doesn't? Each on their own they are good, but the combination of roll/pitch doesn't. Roll/pitch/yaw also does not work properly.

Comment: @RobQuist: That's hard to answer without having more details. What are your values for pitch, roll and yaw, for example?

Comment: I have those stored in degrees (0 - 360), so I'm converting them radians using `r = -d * pi / 180` which seems to work, since individually they work good. I'm thinking it might be an ordering issue - I don't have "yaw pitch roll", but I had xrot, yrot and zrot. Instead of xrot/yrot/zrot being yaw/pitch/roll, i had to translate them to zrot/yrot/xrot being yaw/pitch/roll. I can open up a new question with the code and an example of whats going wrong if thats easier?

Comment: It's not really convenient to share code and to provide context in comments, so yes, I think opening a new question might be easier.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks! I've opened up the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58485284/applying-a-rotation-matrix-on-a-point-with-an-origin-fails

Comment: @MOehm this doesn't rotate correctly unfortunately. I'm trying to rotate an object that I have in stl file. Applying yaw, pitch or roll will rotate the object but the rotation doesn't look correct. Is there a way to rotate the object based on its normal?

Comment: @SolidSnake: The above code is rotating a point about the origin. Is your object at the origin? If you just want to rotate about one axis, only one of the angles is not zero, which simplifies the matrix.

Comment: @MOehm - I'm trying to rotate the object based on its center not the origin. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @MOehm - please check this question I'd really appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242195/rotate-3d-shape-around-its-centeroid-axis

Comment: @SoiidSnake: If the centre of rotaion isn't at the origin, move the object to the origin first, then apply the rotation, then move it back.

Answer (score 15):

From wikipedia:

[image: Rotation Matrices]

If you multiply your points by each of these matrices they will be rotated by the amount you want.

For example, if I want to rotate point `[1, 0, 0]` by 90° around the z axis (in the xy plane), `sin(90) = 1` and `cos(90) = 0` so you get this:

```
| 0 -1  0 |   |1|   |0|
| 1  0  0 | * |0| = |1|
| 0  0  1 |   |0|   |0|
```