# How to rotate a plane in 3d dimensions represented as 1d array in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I represent a 2d plane as a 1d array. I can rotate a plane by an angle in 2d like this: Given a `src` and `dst` plane's, I copy `src` into `dst` rotated by an `angle`, `width` is the width of the plane.

```
function rotatePlane(src, dst, angle, width, height) {
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      let [u, v] = rotate(x, y, angle);

      let iSource = u + v * width,
          iTarget = x, y * width;

      src[iSource] = dst[iTarget];

    }
  }
}

function rotate(a, b, angle) {
  Math.cos(angle) * a - Math.sin(angle) * b,
  Math.sin(angle) * a + Math.cos(angle) * b
}
```

This works, but I want to rotate in 3d dimensions, on all three axises. How can I rotate using this technique?

```js
init();

function init() {
  const width = 256,
        height = 512;

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  
  document.body.append(canvas);
  
  const wPlane = Math.round(width * 0.3),
        hPlane = Math.round(height * 0.15);
  
  const srcPlane = makePlane(wPlane, hPlane);
  dstPlane = makePlane(wPlane, hPlane);
  
  drawLine(srcPlane, Math.round(wPlane / 2), Math.round(hPlane / 2), wPlane);
  
 rotatePlane(srcPlane, dstPlane, Math.PI * 0.2, wPlane, hPlane);
  
  
  
  draw(ctx, srcPlane, 0, 0, wPlane, hPlane);
  draw(ctx, dstPlane, 0, hPlane * 2 + 10, wPlane, hPlane);
}

function rotatePlane3(src, dst, angle3, width, height) {
  // implementation
}

function rotatePlane(src, dst, angle, width, height) {
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      let [u, v] = rotate(x, y, angle);
      [u, v] = [Math.round(u),
                Math.round(v)];
      
      let iSource = u + v * width,
          iTarget = x + y * width;

      dst[iSource] = src[iTarget];

    }
  }
}

function rotate(a, b, angle) {
  return [Math.cos(angle) * a - Math.sin(angle) * b,
  Math.sin(angle) * a + Math.cos(angle) * b];
}

function drawLine(plane, x, y, width) {
  const length = width / 2;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    plane[x + y * width + i] = 'blue';
  }
}

function makePlane(w, h) {
   const res = [];
   
   for (let i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
     res[i] = 'grey';
   }
   return res;
}

function draw(ctx, plane, x, y, w, h) {
   
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(x, y);
   for (let i = 0; i < w; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < h; j++) {
       const color = plane[i + j * w];
       ctx.fillStyle = color;
       ctx.fillRect(i * 2, j * 2, 2, 2);
     }
   }
   ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050929/3d-point-rotation-algorithm/34060479

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/1mev6jzf/41/

Comment: @lara, This rotates points in 3d space, but doesn't map it to 2d