# How would I simulate camera rotation in 3D space by rotating all the points around the position of the camera?

Tags: matrix, graphics, 3d, computer-science

Currently I am working on a simple 3D renderer in Python (I know, probably not the best choice), and I cannot figure out how to make the camera rotate - or more accurately, I cannot figure out how to make a point rotate around the position of the camera in 3D space. I have tried using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050929/3d-point-rotation-algorithm/34060479) which uses a rotation matrix, however this just seems to make the points rotate around themselves.

For example, if I am in a scene with a cube, instead of the cube rotating around the camera, creating the illusion of the camera rotating, the cube will just rotate around itself, so it will just look like there is a cube rotating.

Hopefully this is an obvious solution, I can post my code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In order to rotate about an arbitrary point in space:

- first, translate that point to the origin
- then, rotate about the origin
- finally, translate the origin back to the original point.

Given the rotation point `p`, and the rotation matrix `R`:

```
def rot_about_point(p, R, x):
  return translate(p) @ R @ translate(-p) @ x
```

The above code assumes `x` is a column vector (homogeneous 4-vector), so that matrices multiply them on the left, and geometric transformations read right to left.