# Rotate 3D point around another 3D Point

Tags: 3d, rotation, point, pawn

yes, i have been searching other posts on stackoverflow, but mostly i don't understand them or i don't know how to implement it in my scripting language.

I want to rotate a 3D point around another 3D point, i have a parent 3D point with 3D rotation and child 3D points with 3D rotation, how can i rotate the child points around the parent point keeping the rotation informations?

Scripting language is PAWN, but C language is also fine(Because it's similar), i know i have to use those functions:

- floatcos(Float:angle, anglemode(radian, degrees or grades));
- floatsin(Float:angle, anglemode(radian, degrees or grades));
- floattan(Float:angle, anglemode(radian, degrees or grades));

Parent point and Child points have those coords:
X(Left Right), Y(Front Back), Z(This is Up and Down)
RX(Rotation Pitch), RY(Rotation Roll), RZ(Rotation Yaw)

Red is the Parent Point
Blue are the child points

[Click here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuaSp.jpg)

I hope you guys can help me, i'm really bad at math and i need this to work somehow :/

Comment: One can rotate a point around a vector, but not around another point.  Do you intend on one point representing a vector from the origin?  You'd also need to specify how much of a rotation (in degrees or another angular unit).  How much do you want to rotate it?  You might check out this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050929/3d-point-rotation-algorithm?rq=1

Comment: Well for example, my parent point is at X: 10 Y: 45 Z: 5 and the Child point is at X: -8 Y: 105 Z: 11, now i need to rotate the child position AROUND the parent point on the X, Y, Z axis. How to do that?

Comment: Does around mean 180 degrees?  You could do it like this.  Let's call the first point p1 and the second p2.  Then the rotated point will be p2 + (p2 - p1).

Comment: Around means from 0-360 degrees, it's a variable i get from the parent point, i get the X, Y, Z Rotation of the parent point and i need to calculate the new X, Y, Z position of child point(s) using the parent rotation.

Comment: What do you mean by _keeping the rotation informations_? What's the point of the child points' rotation information?

Comment: What are X, Y, Z, RX, RY, RZ: simple variables, symbolic subscripts? What are the coordinates: integer, float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i did it using a Rotation Matrix library, it calculates the world position from all attached objects from the parents position and rotation.

A user from a math forum suggested this and it works
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.