# Rotate 3D point around 3D origin in radians using transformation matrices

Tags: javascript, 3d, linear-algebra

I am attempting to make a function that can rotate a given 3D point around a 3D origin using transformation matrices.

I do not have experience with linear Algebra, so this is purely based on research.

I saw various other questions on the same topic, but I could not find a clear response.

This is based on the QNA from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34052492/10448256

[image]

My thought was to get the XYZ point and subtract the origin.

From here, multiply the XYZ point by the Rx matrix, take those points and multiply by Ry, and then Rz. Return the point + origin.

This led to the following program:

```
function rotatePointXYZ(point, origin, rad) {
  let ox = origin[0];
  let oy = origin[1];
  let oz = origin[2];
  let px = point[0] - ox;
  let py = point[1] - oy;
  let pz = point[2] - oz;
  let tx = rad[0];
  let ty = rad[1];
  let tz = rad[2];
  let rx = [1, 0, 0, 0, Math.cos(tx), -Math.sin(tx), 0, Math.sin(tx), Math.cos(tx)];
  let ry = [Math.cos(ty), 0, Math.sin(ty), 0, 1, 0, -Math.sin(ty), 0, Math.cos(ty)];
  let rz = [Math.cos(tz), -Math.sin(tz), 0, Math.sin(tz), Math.cos(tz), 0, 0, 0, 1];
  let rotatedX = [(rx[0] * px + rx[1] * py + rx[2] * pz), (rx[3] * px + rx[4] * py + rx[5] * pz), (rx[6] * px + rx[7] * py + rx[8] * pz)];
  px = rotatedX[0];
  py = rotatedX[1];
  pz = rotatedX[2];
  let rotatedY = [(ry[0] * px + ry[1] * py + ry[2] * pz), (ry[3] * px + ry[4] * py + ry[5] * pz), (ry[6] * px + ry[7] * py + ry[8] * pz)];
  px = rotatedY[0];
  py = rotatedY[1];
  pz = rotatedY[2];
  let rotatedZ = [(rz[0] * px + rz[1] * py + rz[2] * pz), (rz[3] * px + rz[4] * py + rz[5] * pz), (rz[6] * px + rz[7] * py + rz[8] * pz)];
  px = rotatedZ[0];
  py = rotatedZ[1];
  pz = rotatedZ[2];
  return [px + ox, py + oy, pz + oz]
}

console.log(rotatePointXYZ([1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2, 0]))
```

The issue is that this function is also rotating the coordinate within the z-axis despite the angle of rotation being zero radians.

Red is the origin, Orange is pre-rotation, and yellow is post-rotation.

[image]

It seems to rotate on the XY plain correctly.

[image]

But is also rotating on the z-axis when it should not:

[image]