# How do I write a formula that rotates a point around the coordination systems center?

Tags: processing, trigonometry

In Processing, I have a 3D coordination system where x, y, and z dimensions span from 0 to 1000. I have a point randomly placed within these coordinates, and want it to rotate around the center (x, y and z = 500) by a given angle. I want to recalculate the point coordinates instead of relying on the translate(), or rotateX()/rotateY()/rotateZ() methods.

What is the mathematical formula for each of the x, y, and z coordinates? How can i express the formulas in code? (The searches I've done doesn't come up with answers specific to my case).

Comment: But, your question, seems to be a duplicate of: [3D point rotation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050929/3d-point-rotation-algorithm) or [Rotating a Vector in 3D Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607640/rotating-a-vector-in-3d-space)

Comment: @Luuk The language is [Processing](https://processing.org/) as clearly specified with the [tag:processing] tag.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a point around an arbitrary center in a 3D space, you can utilize rotation matrices. These matrices allow you to perform rotations around the x, y, and z axes by specific angles. In Processing, to rotate a point (x, y, z) around the center (500, 500, 500), you'll need to apply translations, perform the rotation, and then translate back to the original position.

The steps involve:

Moving the point to the origin by subtracting the center coordinates.
Utilizing the suitable rotation matrix for the desired axis.
Moving the point back to its original position by adding the center coordinates.
Here's an example for rotating a point (x, y, z) around the center (500, 500, 500) by an angle theta around the x-axis:

```
float x = 300; // Example point coordinates`
float y = 700;
float z = 400;

float centerX = 500;
float centerY = 500;
float centerZ = 500;

float theta = radians(45); // Angle in radians

// Move the point to the origin
x -= centerX;
y -= centerY;
z -= centerZ;

// Perform rotation around x-axis
float newY = y * cos(theta) - z * sin(theta);
float newZ = y * sin(theta) + z * cos(theta);

// Move the point back to the original position
x += centerX;
newY += centerY;
newZ += centerZ;

// Updated point coordinates
println("New Coordinates:");
println("x: " + x);
println("y: " + newY);
println("z: " + newZ);
```

By adapting this code and using different rotation matrices for the y and z axes, you can perform rotations around these axes as well.

For rotation around the y-axis by angle theta:

```
|  cosθ   0  sinθ |
|   0       1    0   |
| -sinθ  0  cosθ |
```

For rotation around the z-axis by angle theta:

```
|  cosθ  -sinθ  0  |
|  sinθ   cosθ  0  |
|   0        0      1 |
```